# Resizing image worsens resolution

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this method to resize my image:

```
func imageToResizedImage(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

However, when I resize it to smaller (50% smaller, for example), I find that the resolution got worse. It gets blurry.

What can I add to my code so that the resolution is still sharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` creates a context with a scale factor of 1.0, which doesn’t match the screen resolution of any modern iOS device (2.0 or 3.0). From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext):

> This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of 1.0.

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead; if you pass it a scale factor of 0.0, it will default to the scale of the device’s main screen.